# Cannot get SVN repository on local machine

Tags: php, svn, centos, tortoisesvn

I have created a repo on the remote server (Linux - CentOS) and now I want to get the repo on my local machine (Windows - TortoiseSVN), but when I am doing the checkout, it gives me

> Unexpected http 400 status error

I have tried using all the URL: http, https, svn, svn+ssh, but nothing works.

I have checked all the previous posts related to this but nothing helped.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you run `svn info` on the remote server are you svning the path provided there?.. or is remote server your own SVN server?

Comment: its resolved.. I was using TortoiseSVN 1.9 version, i guess it is a bug on that version. SO uninstalled it and installed TortoiseSVN 1.7 version and it worked fine.. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score -1):

its resolved.. I was using TortoiseSVN 1.9 version, i guess it is a bug on that version. SO uninstalled it and installed TortoiseSVN 1.7 version and it worked fine..
And then changed the user for the repo folder and all its subdirectories and files to apache:apache using chown -R apache:apache repo_folder 
Also gave the permissions with the command chmod -R 775 repo_folder and it worked fine.
Thank you for your comments